# How to make return in text field call function Swift/Cocoa

Tags: swift, cocoa

Apologies in advance for my total noobness in the Cocoa UI. I'm trying to make hitting the return key in a text field call a function in Swift 2.1/Xcode 7/OSX project. Here's what I have:

```
class MainWindowController: NSWindowController, NSTextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var textBox: NSTextField! 
    init() {
        super.init( window: nil )
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed( windowNibName, owner: self, topLevelObjects: nil )      
        textBox.delegate = self
    }   
    func textDidEndEditing ( textField: NSTextField! ) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        monkeyBoy()
        return true
    } 
    func monkeyBoy() {
        print( "Hello there" )
    }
    //...
}
```

Questions:

1. Is this correct thus far? Am I missing anything or have something wrong?
2. How do I wire up `textDidEndEditing` to `textBox`? In IB? If so, would you be so kind as to tell me how? To this IB noob, it is one confusing cockpit :)

Comment: *slaps palm to forehead* @leodabus any way I can get it to point to the same function as a button other to break out the function and have both of the IBactions call it?

Comment: You can just create another method and just call it from there and from the button

Comment: Or just change the sender to AnyObject

Comment: Man, I wish that I could click the up button more than once on that last comment, @leodabus ;)